# Can't add column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to change to name of an existing column, but got `MySQL error 1064`.

So I then dropped the column to re-ad it with the new name, but got the same error... I'm starting to worry it's something with the db itself since I can't find any error in the phpmyadmin generated query:

```
ALTER TABLE `Schools` 
ADD `SchoolName` VARCHAR(65) CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL
AFTER `SchoolId`;
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: 1064 usually means some kind of syntax error if memory serves me right. Should the charset and collate not be in quotes as well?

Comment: That's correct @Ewald, but as far as I'm concerned there's nothing wrong with this query (I tried adding the column using phpmyadmin gui first, but when that didn't work I started to check it manually but I can't see any mistake...)

Comment: I think that = sign is the problem - never seen an equals used like that before.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is your problem :

```
CHARSET=latin1
```

Remove the "=" sign.

Comment: omg... it actually was the "=" sign.. But how in the world does phpmyadmin end up trying it with "="?

Comment: Well... It's probably a bug, or some obscure setting somewhere. That's just computers for you, always finding a way to mess with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE  `Schools` ADD  `SchoolName` VARCHAR( 65 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL AFTER  `SchoolId`
```

and next

```
ALTER TABLE Schools CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1
```

Comment: You can do both in a single statement, the CHARSET doesn't take an = sign - your solution would work as well. Good thinking breaking it up into steps.

Comment: this works too indeed, but my query is generated by phpmyadmin so simply replacing the "=" with a whitespace is much simpler